# Trace requests to ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-vpc

I have a Fargate managed ECS cluster (with an HTTP actix-web server) behind a Network Load Balancer.
I have two different graphql requests which are being sent to that server (`my.server/graphql/requestA` and `my.server/graphql/requestB`). requestA's response is instantaneous whereas requestB's response takes anywhere between 5 and 50 seconds.
Upon sending one requestB and multiple requestA (right after sending requestB) I see that a couple of A remain pending and fail (sometimes all fail with a 408, otherwise the first would show a 502 and the remaining would show a 408) when B is returned successfully. This is most probably due to not having enough workers on the backend.

I want to trace the requests from my browser to my backend and ensure that they are failing due to a fault at the backend. I have access to the CloudFront logs where I can see requests coming in from my public IP. I also have access to my VPC flowLogs where I can see requests coming in from the NLB to the ECS target. However, I am unable to join those two and figure out which exact request failed in the VPC logs.

I tried turning on the `Preserve client IP addresses` flag for my target group but it still shows me the NLB's private IP address and not my public IP address.

Is it even possible to trace a request in this manner?

Comment: Have you tried access log of NLB?https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-access-logs.html

Comment: @TsalTroser what fields do I use to verify my doubt? In the logs I can see my NLB's private IPv4 as the destination:port